# Oracle proceduce

Tags: oracle

```
create or replace procedure tt
is
begin
  select leasestation,returnstation
  from system.t_123
       leasedate>='2014-02-23';
end tt;

alter procedure tt compile;

exec tt
```

It doesn't work, SQL server and Oracle have so much differences,how should i do to make sure it can work on Oracle

Comment: what should this procedure do?

Answer (score 1):

It won't work without an `INTO` e.g. `SELECT INTO` some variable(s).  PL/SQL doesn't allow you to just return data without something like a `CURSOR`.

If you want to return the data from the `SELECT` statement as a Dataset, you'll need to use a `REF CURSOR` to store the result set and then have that `REF CURSOR` be an `OUT` parameter.

Some light reading:

- [Example: Returning a REF CURSOR from a procedure (PL/SQL)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.plsql.doc/doc/c0053892.html). You'll want to use the first example in that article.
- [Using PL/SQL Stored Procedures and REF CURSORs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/appdev.112/e18751/procedures_plsql.htm#TDPNG60000)